# Compiling C Header File with netinet/ether.h on Windows

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm trying to compile (using cygwin) a C header file that includes netinet/ether.h. On Linux I can compile the header file but on Windows it can't find netinet/ether.h.  What's the best way to include the proper netinet/ether.h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what exactly you need from `netinet/ether.h`, but the general answer is that there is no good way, and you'll have to provide some sort of workaround.

In particular, the [Gnulib documentation](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gnulib/manual/html_node/Glibc-netinet_002fether_002eh.html#Glibc-netinet_002fether_002eh) for `ether.h` notes for all of the functions in there, "This function is missing on some platforms: HP-UX 11, Cygwin, mingw, Interix 3.5, BeOS."

More generally, these are fairly low-level networking headers that relate to technology provided by the operating system, and it's entirely possible (and, in fact, likely) that Cygwin may not be able to provide access to the Windows networking system in a way that would match what Linux provides.  This is why porting software from one system to another is not a completely trivial exercise!